# How to print index position x86 Assemby

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, irvine32

I am new to Assembly and trying to get a homework done, I want to know how to print the index position of an array instead of the value at index, I'm using ESI as pointer. Here the array is filled with 0's and 1's and I want to print the index of the 1's only.
Sample array [1|1|0|0|1]

```
PRINT:  
    mov eax,[esi]
    cmp eax,1
    je Show
    add esi,4
    loop PRINT
Show:   
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    loop Show
```

Output should be (1 2 5) or (0 1 4).
Thanks.

Comment: Count. Just like you do with `esi` but start from 0 or 1 and step by 1.

Comment: You don't show how the array is defined. In Assembly definition and structure of data are often more important than the code itself. Without the definition it's difficult to tell whether your code works as is, and can be just modified to answer you, or whether it already contain some bug (for example `mov eax,[esi]` looks highly suspicious .. but from `add esi,4` it looks ok). [mcve] is very important with Assembly.

Comment: But... thinking about it again, maybe this question makes more sense without the code at all, as for the homework I find valid if you ask for the method/principle, how to resolve it, than for the solutions code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either add a counter:

```
mov ebx,1           ; index counter, first element = 1
PRINT:  
    mov eax,[esi]
    cmp eax,1
    jne noShow

    mov eax,ebx          
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
noShow:
    add esi,4
    inc ebx         ; increase counter
    loop PRINT
```

or calculate it from ESI ( assuming ESI = ARRAY + 4* Index )

```
PRINT:  
    mov eax,[esi]
    cmp eax,1
    jne noShow

    mov eax, esi       ; load position in index
    sub eax, ARRAY     ; remove starting position of the array
    shr eax, 2         ; divide it by 4, to get index position
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

noShow:
    add esi,4
    loop PRINT
```

(PS: Fixed the looping logic, which was wrong in the question)

(PSS: I cannot test the code atm, i'm at work )

Comment: The code is already wrong in OP's post... the last `loop Show` doesn't make sense. In your first variant it's even worse, as it's not easy to fix it, because you will update `ebx` only in one path.

Comment: There is a typo in `shr eax, 4`. Should be 2

Answer (score 1):

You have to start with @MargaretBloom's idea, count, also it's necessary to fix some other errors in the algorithm :

- You have two `loop`, the problem is, when the first `loop` ends, the next block of code executes, and `eax` is printed again, and an infinite loop starts.
- Your second `loop` jumps to `Show` but it should jump to `PRINT`.
- You are increasing `esi` after `je Show`, so the index is not incremented when a value of `1` is found, `esi` should be incremented **before**.

Let's fix those little problems, I will use `edi` as the **position** you want to display (you can use any other register) :

```
    mov edi, 0       ;◄■■ THIS IS THE POSITION YOU WANT TO DISPLAY (1,2,3,...).
PRINT:     
    mov eax,[esi]
    add esi,4        ;◄■■ INCREMENT INDEX HERE.
    inc edi          ;◄■■ INCREASE POSITION (1,2,3,...).
    cmp eax,1
    je Show
    loop PRINT
    jmp  Finish      ;◄■■ SKIP NEXT BLOCK WHEN FINISH.
Show:   
    mov  eax, edi    ;◄■■ DISPLAY POSITION.
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    loop PRINT       ;◄■■ JUMP TO PRINT, NOT TO SHOW.

Finish:
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to ... index position of an array ... ESI as pointer

First the definition of the array is important, if it's simple flat array consisting of consecutive elements, then to get index of particular element pointed at by address `EDI` you can reverse calculate it from the two pointers involved (this requires the original start-of-array pointer still in `ESI`!):

```
mov  eax,edi
sub  eax,esi      ; eax = (element_pointer - array_pointer)
; divide eax by <size_of_element>

; for example your OP code example suggest
; the array element size is DWORD = 4B
; then the division/4 can be done simply:
; shr   eax,2

; for byte arrays there's no need to divide the address
; difference, eax already contains index, as BYTE size = 1B

; for other element sizes, which are *not* power-of-two
; (you can't divide the difference by simply shifting it right)
; it may be more efficient to address them through separate index
; or do the: imul/mul (1/el_size) || idiv/div el_size
; (when there's no way to avoid it)

; after division the eax contains 0, 1, ... index.
```

If the size of element is non trivial (not power-of-two), or the structure is not trivial (linked list so difference of two pointers doesn't correlate with index of element), you may want to count index separately. Still to avoid `mul element_size` of index for every fetch it may be worth to mix the two, so addressing through pointers, and counting (useless for fetching) index separately, which will be used only for the thing where you need index.

Plus in this variant you can index from `1`, but I would avoid that unless it's some human output for non-programmer, as most of the ASM/C/C++ programmers are naturally expecting indexing to start at `0` (due to the how-pointer-math works in my first example).

```
; stolen from Toommylee2k, then modified to focus on my explanation

    xor  ebx,ebx         ; first index will be 1 (!)
    ; so I initialized ebx = 1 - 1 = 0, because
    ; I will increment it at beginning of loop

    ; for indexing from 0 the ebx should be initialized to -1

loop_start:
    ; update index first, so you can't miss it when branching later
    lea  ebx,[ebx+1] ; ebx = ebx+1 without flags modification

    ; since *here* "ebx" works as "index", contains "1" for first item

    ; do whatever you want with pointers, like "esi" in your sample code
    ; ...

    ; move to next element of array (avoids multiplication)
    add esi,size_of_element
    ; although `imul` on modern CPU will perform quite close to `add`
    ; so when multiplication is unavoidable, go for it.

    ; the division on the other hand still costs very likely more
    ; than having separate register/variable for index counting

    ; loop till ecx is zero (in much faster way than "loop")
    dec ecx
    jnz loop_start
    ; "loop" is very slow due to historic reasons, to improve compatibility
```

---

And final extension, when the element size is one of [1, 2, 4, 8], you can use extended x86 addressing mode to work with "0, 1, ..." index instead of pure pointers:

```
mov   ebx,7    ; index "7" = 8th element of array
lea   esi,[array_of_words]  ; array pointer

; addressing through index, supported directly by CPU for size 2
mov   ax,[esi + ebx*2]      ; complex x86 addressing allows this

; here ax = 8
...

.data
array_of_words:
    dw  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

If you use the indices in the loop quite a bit, this may be the most optimal solution. If you need index of element only rarely, pure pointers are usually more optimal.